# Simultaneous pipe to grep and redirect to stdout

Tags: redirect, grep, stdout

In Linux bash, I am trying to run a command and grep for an argument:

```
command | grep
```

However, I need to redirect the result of the **commad** to the stdout and simultaneously pipe it to grep (I need to see both the **grep** result and the **command** result in stdout).

I googled a bit and tried some variations, such as:

```
command | tee /dev/tty | grep
```

But, no luck.

I don't want to use sth like

```
command
command | grep
```

as it is ugly :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
command | tee >(grep whatever)
```

Note that there's no space between these two symbols: `>(`.

Comment: Thanks, this solve my original problem, but add additional problem
Here is my code :

snmpget -v2c -c public 10.241.32.42 .1.3.6.1.4.1.28589.2.5.96.0 | tee >(grep -E "STRING: \"[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}\"") ;;
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28589.2.5.96.0 = "" 
;;
echo $?;;
0;;
}}}

The exit status of "command | tee >(grep) is "0"" no matter if the grep is successful or not.

Comment: what is you want ALL output to go to a file, in addition ALL output piped to the grep command?