# Exit status of tee>(...)

Tags: tee, subshell, exitstatus

I am executing:

```
Command1 | tee >(grep sth) || Command2
```

I want **Command2** to be executed based on the exit status of **grep**, while in the current configuration it is being executed based on the result of **tee**.

As far as I know pipefail and pipestatus are not working here (please correct me if I am wrong).

**Modification to the Origian question based on Alexej Answer**

I also tried `Command1 | tee >(grep sth || Command2)`, which works for my original question, but as I am trying to set the status of my test in the subshell; ex, `Command 1 | tee>(grep sth || Result="PASSED")` and later have access to the **Result** in other chunks of my code. So I still have problem.

Thanks

Comment: does `command1 | tee | grep sth` not work?  Is there any reason why you need to use a subshell?

Comment: I need to log the output of "Command1" and also the output of "grep" (some device testing requirement). By using pipe, I cannot record the output of the "Command1". An alternative is to execute Command1, log the output, then execute it for second time and pipe it to grep, which is ugly :). "command1 | tee | grep sth" redirect the stdout to grep. Here is my 1st question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066559/simultaneous-pipe-to-grep-and-redirect-to-stdout/23066748?noredirect=1#23066748 that leaded me to use subshell and ....

Comment: okay, so you're saying that `if (command1 | tee | grep sth &> /dev/null); then command2; fi` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script to:

```
Command1 | tee >(grep sth || Command2)
```

to achieve the desired result.

#### A word about Subshells

`>(....)` is a subshell.  Anything and everything that you do within that subshell (except for the exit status of said subshell) is *completely* isolated from the outside world: `(a=1); echo $a` will never echo the number `1`, because `a` *only* has meaning within the subshell where it is defined.

I don't entirely understand why, but when you do redirection to a subshell, it seems to invert the exit status of that subshell, so that a failure will return `true` and a success will return `false`.

```bash
echo 'a' >(grep 'b') && echo false
# false
(exit 1) || echo false
# false
```

So if my first suggestion isn't working out for you, then try re-writing your script thusly:

```bash
Command1 | tee >(grep sth) && Command2
```

#### An example

```bash
a=1 # `a` now equals `1`
# if I run `exit`, $a will go out of scope and the terminal I'm in might exit
(exit) # $a doesn't go out of scope because `exit` was run from within a subshell.
echo $a # $a still equals `1`
```

#### Where you can go to learn more about subshells

[Set a parent shell's variable from a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541321/set-a-variable-from-a-subshell)
[Pass variable from a child to parent in KSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383082/pass-variable-from-a-child-to-parent-in-ksh/15383353#15383353)
[Variables value gets lost in subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085518/variables-value-gets-lost-in-subshell)
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst

Comment: I still have some problem: 
Coomand1 |  tee >(grep sth || Command2) works perfectly, but Coomand1 |  tee >(grep sth || var1=sth) does not work. Is there any reason that I cannot assign an argument in this configuration.

Comment: what do you mean by "I cannot assign an argument in this config..."?  Do you mean that it runs just fine, but you can't access the variable?

Comment: Assume that I assigned {var1=2}, then later I am running {Command1 | tee >(grep sth || var1=3)} (Command | tee >(grep sth) exit status is 0). Later, I check for the $var1 which is still 2, while it should be 3.

Comment: @Aman I've updated my answer to address the variable issue that you're encountering.

Comment: Thx, I updated the question as well (based on your answer) as I am still struggling with it.